# Is it possible to latex a document in TexShop from a file which isn't the master file?

Tags: mac, latex, texshop

For large documents I tend to use \input{chapterX.tex} for, say, each chapter. In TexShop, is it possible to latex from, say, chapterX.tex instead of the master file? This is possible for instance in auctex. I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. At the top of your chapterX.tex, include the following line:

```
%!TEX root = main.tex
```

where `main.tex` is the main file that has the `\input{chapterX.tex}` line. When you next open chapterX.tex, it will also open main.tex. When you hit Typeset at chapterX.tex, the focus will switch to main.tex and it will run latex on that file.